# Context file not loading tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, webdeploy

I created a dynamic web project and added a `context.xml` file to the `META-INF` folder as mentioned [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context). But when I deploy the war file the context file is not copying to the folder `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/`. My `context.xml` file content are following,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>    
    <Environment name="test" value="10"
         type="java.lang.Integer" override="false"/> 
</Context>
```

Why this approach is not working? How can I set the context of a application dynamically?

Comment: Why don't you try by putting it at `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/`?

Comment: It says "Optionally (based on the Host's copyXML attribute) this may be copied to $CATALINA_BASE...". It means Tomcat is not going to copy it for you, you will have to copy it yourself.. right? :/

Comment: yes @aksappy.  I am very new to deploying a web application. It will be great if you could  brief  the `Host's copyXML attribute`.

Comment: Sure @SabirKhan, I will try that.

Comment: Host element is in your server.xml, inside your <Engine> tag. Update it to have copyXML="true"

Comment: Thanks @aksappy. It's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating the Host element inside your  tag.

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        ...
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" copyXML="true">
```